# .net DataGridView Programmatically Select only

Tags: .net, datagridview

I don't want users to be able to select rows. [selectionmode = none]

Anyways my application needs to select rows in the datagridview to highlight them. [selectionmode = none won't work then] [use enabled = false]

Also the user has to be able to scroll in the datagridview [enabled = false won't work then as well]

Is there a way to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ReadOnly` instead of `.Enabled` property to enable scrollbar.

Then you can use `CellFormatting` event to highlight cells and `SelectionChanged` event to disable user selection.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If e.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
    ElseIf Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("YourTestField").Value = "YourValue" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged

    Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

End Sub
```